# Find all hashtags in tweets using TweepyV2

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to get hashtags from all tweets using TweepyV4. To get hashtags for each tweet I need to add needed expansion and look in the tweet_field 'entity' as per the documentation.

```
    for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_tweets, user_id,
                                     exclude='replies,retweets',
                                     max_results=100,
                                     expansions='referenced_tweets.id',
                                     tweet_fields=['entities']):
           
        for tweets in response.data:
            print(tweets['entities']['hashtags'])
```

This is giving me a key Error. Does anyone know why entities does not contain hashtags?

Update:

```
    tweet_list = []
    for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_tweets, user_id,
                                     exclude='replies,retweets',
                                     max_results=100,
                                     expansions='referenced_tweets.id',
                                     tweet_fields=['created_at','public_metrics','entities']):
        for tweets in response.data:
            tweet_list.append([tweets.text,
                               tweets['public_metrics']['like_count'],
                               tweets['public_metrics']['retweet_count'],
                               tweets['created_at'].date()])
        for tweets in response.data:
            print(tweets['entities']['hashtags'])

    df = pd.DataFrame(tweet_list, columns=["Tweet", "Favourites", "Retweets", "Created"])
    return df
```

This is my complete function for reading tweets. I get everything else 'like_count',created_at' etc.  When I try to access hashtags from entities it shows Key Error.

Comment: What does the data returned in response look like? It is difficult to say without being able to see what you are getting back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
Found the answer. Tweets without entities were returning None. That was the issue. Now this gives me all hashtags in all tweets.

```
  if tweets['entities'] is not None:
            for key, value in tweets['entities'].items():
                if key == 'hashtags':
                    for hashtag in value:
                        hashtag_list.append(hashtag['tag'])
```